# Ping a list of IP addresses and outputing duplicates

Tags: linux, ping, duplicate

In Linux how can I ping a list of IP addresses (in a text file) and only output those that have duplicate ping replies?

Comment: what do you mean by " duplicate ping replies" ?

Comment: I guess duplicate replies are described in the man page: "ping  will  report  duplicate  and  damaged packets.  Duplicate packets should never occur, and seem to be caused by inappropriate link-level retransmissions.  Duplicates may occur in many situations and are rarely (if ever) a good sign, although the presence of low levels of duplicates may not always  be  cause  for alarm."

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about duplicates described in the man page:

```
Duplicate packets should never occur, and seem to be caused by 
inappropriate link-level retransmissions. Duplicates may occur 
in many situations and are rarely (if ever) a good sign, although 
the presence of low levels of duplicates may not always be cause 
for alarm.
```

It will produce output like this:

```
$ ping -n 192.x.y.z
PING x.com (192.x.y.z) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.x.y.z: icmp_req=1 ttl=120 time=51.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.x.y.z: icmp_req=1 ttl=120 time=51.8 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.x.y.z: icmp_req=1 ttl=120 time=52.3 ms (DUP!)
```

So you have just to iterate over the list in cycle:

```
while read ip ; do ping -c4 $ip | grep -q 'DUP!' && echo "$ip duplicates" ; done < ip_list.txt
```

Where ip_list.txt contains new line separated ip addresses list.

Comment: thanks you for the fast reply . but have you ever noticed that sometimes you can ping an ip address using an online ping tool and it gives you a reply but when you use the linux terminal it doesn't give you a ping reply. what could be the problem ?  find it very strange. or could it be my isp blocking the duplicate ping relies ?

Comment: my `ping` does not understand `-c` : `ping -c4` gives error message
`Incorrect option -c4.` along with the usage text. I have an option `-n count` to ask for _count_ echos. Does your `-c4` mean `-n 4`? (In case others have the same ping as I...)